# cut rows from one table and paste them into another table

Tags: mysql

I want to cut rows from one table and paste them into another table.
is there a mysql command that does this job ?

```
table1(id, field1, field2, fields3 )
table2(id, field1, field2, fields3 )
```

Comment: Check [INSERT INTO SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: But that wont CUT the values from the origin table, it will just do a copy. [Tutorial](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-into-select/)

Comment: I fear you will have to do two operations, the first one being the copy, the second being the delete. I believe that is how 'Cut' operations over partition boundaries work as well (where it is not a mere matter of altering a directory entry).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's assume we need to copy a row from TableOld to TableNew.
First we will copy the row from `TableOld` to `TableNew`.

```
INSERT INTO TableNew
SELECT * FROM TableOld
WHERE [Conditions]
```

Now we will delete the row from TableOld.

```
DELETE * FROM TableOld
WHERE [Conditions]
```

Comment: I dont think this is adding anything much to the comments already made

Comment: yes that's what I wanted to know, so I have to proceed by 2 operations. so there is no command to do the job.

Comment: SQL does not provide the cut operation, so you will have to copy and then delete the row.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'cut - paste' command in mysql, however you can start a transaction and insert into one table then delete from the other one.

Lets say you have the following 2 tables

```
create table cut (
ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Field1 INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

create table paste (
ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Field1 INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

You want to insert some test data:

```
insert cut set Field1="1";
```

Then, you need to 'copy' from one table to another one using insert and select. At last, you want to remove from 'cut' table as follows

```
start transaction;
insert into paste (Field1) select Field1 from cut where id=1;
delete from cut where id=1;
commit;
```